# Why do we need the second parameter for add_graph() when using tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard

As we know, there are two parameters for `add_graph()`, a first parameter is an object of the model that we want to visualize, and the second parameter is just an input for the model. The input can be quite casual, i.e., we can simply randomly generate an input with the shape we want and feed it to `add_graph()`. So what’s the point to have the input as a parameter? It seems to me that this parameter only provides the shape information of an input tensor, but we can directly get this information from the model definition, right? And no matter what input we feed to `add_graph()`, the computation graph printed by tensorboard is always the same. I am really confused about this.

Comment: Can you please explain your question by adding some code so that community can understand it and we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowWarrior I'm having the same question here, and I think it's pretty straightforward. For example, this is the function signature: `writer.add_graph(model, input_to_model=None, verbose=False)`,  you can see there is an `input_to_model` arg, and I have to pass this arg to this function, otherwise this function raises an error. And how can we just visualize the graph, WITHOUT passing any input args?